# pycharm svn checksum error

Tags: svn, pycharm

The path of our svn server cahgned, so I deleted the checkout I was working with and added the new checkout. Everything in windows works fine, I can update and commit without any problems. However, when I try to commit through pyCharm, I get the following error

svn: E200014: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200014: Base checksum mismatch on '/prod/filexyz.py':
   expected:  5d4b969299b4454b8ded988572834384
     actual:  3867004bd2a2e11e2f02d1a963d2b4d8
svn: E175002: PUT of '/prod/!svn/wrk/bf794813-4601-0010-a6fb-bd9d5f886d99/prod/filexyz.py': 500 Internal Server Error (http://svn.loc)

This shows up with any file I change and try to commit. 
I re installed pyCharm, but that does not help.

Any ideas how I can fix this?